# How to make sure that two element having common attribute never be multithreaded in a parallelized for loop (in C#)?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

Hi every one and thanks a lot for helping me with this :)

Well what I want to do is quite simple. Let's take an example.

```
class Human{
    object someObject1;
    object someObject2;
    object someObject3;
    void modifyObject(){
        //[...] do some stuff that may require time and can modify someObject1 2 and 3 
    }
}

class Children : Human{
     Human Parent1;
     Human Parent2;
}
```

I consider this for loop:

```
foreach( var e in listOHumans){
     e.Parent1.modifyObject();
     e.Parent2.modifyObject();
}
```

What I want is to parallelize this for loop.
The problem is that a thread `t1` and another `t2`, could do the job on two different children of a same parent. If `t1` and `t2` do an `modifyObject` at the same moment. Which I mthink could mess with the someObject1 2 and 3. *(What I want is to make sure that two children **having a common parent** will never be multithreaded at the same time in oder to have corrects someObject1 2 and 3 all over the for loop).*

What is the best way to do that in C# ?

I consider a list of 10M Humans, only 5% have common parents. Which means parallelisation could be usefull, but I definitely do not want `modifyObject()` to be called simulteanously on a same instance by two different thread.

Comment: is this homework?

Comment: The question and contrived example is confusing to say the least. First, you don't need nor should you attempt to use raw threads when PLINQ and Parallel.For/Foreach are available. Second, if you modify data in parallel the problem becomes orders of magnitude *harder*. Finally, adding items to lists doesn't require parallelization.

Comment: No, it is not. However, I simplified my problem and considered Human and Parents because it was easier to explain what I want to do => make sure that two INSTANCES in a list I have having a common ATTRIBUTE will never be multithreaded at the same time

Comment: Now, if you remove all of the text and leave only `I want to count how many children every single Human are having.`, or rephrase it to `How can I aggregate a hierarchical structure?` you can start looking for answers, *assuming* there are enough data to justify parallelization. One option is to flatten the hierarchy and simply take a Count, eg with an iterator method and SelectMany

Comment: yes, I'm not looking to "adding items to lists ". But definitively looking to parallelize the for loops in which the called function do "modify data ".

Comment: @StudentInFinance provide a meaningful example then. And don't modify data. You don't need to modify data to count, average, or calculate statistics

Comment: Ok, I'll improve the example

Comment: @StudentInFinance post the *actual* problem, don't try to simplify or explain it. You can probably google for the name ordescription of the algorithm and `parallelize` and come up with answers or blog posts that implement it already

Answer (score -2):

When you are using multithreaded operations, you have to `lock` your object when you are using it, to avoid computational errors.

```
class Human{
    object someObject1;
    object someObject2;
    object someObject3;
    void modifyObject(){
        lock (someObject1)
        {   
            //some operation with someObject1
        }
        lock (someObject2)
        lock (someObject3)
        {   
            //some operation with someObject2 and someObject3
        }
    }
}
```

this will make sure you NEVER modify an object from two threads simultaneously.

Comment: If all you do is increment a variable you don't need to lock anything

Comment: yes you do. variable++ is equalent to variable = variable + 1, which is not an atomic operation.

Comment: No you don't. You use a simple. `.Length`. Or you use `.Count()`. Or you use `Interlocked.Increment` although that's overkill. The very idea of modifying state simply to count is wrong.

Comment: `ParallelEnumerable` has its own `Count()`, Sum, Aggregate etc just like `Enumerable` does

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You are right, a Count() would be better, but if you don't want to use LINQ, and you are incrementing a variable, then you do have to lock it.

Comment: *DON'T* increment a variable then. Just because the OP used a naive implementation doesn't mean that it should be used. *Locking* disables parallelization so you might as well run everything on the same thread. In the rare case that you do need to increment a variable, DON'T lock, use Interlocked.Increment which doesn't lock

Comment: Ok, my example was quite bad since, the operation is not meant to be atomic. __ I thought parallelisation could be great since only 5% of my children have a common parent. (Let's consider a list of 10M Humans).

Comment: You can try this implementation, if you don't reference much of the objects, than this will not disable paralellism

Comment: I'll give it a try. And I'll let you informed of the improvements it gives. Thanks :)

Comment: Hope it works. I was thinking, maybe you need to lock your object2 and object3 instead of anchor. I can't remember now.

Comment: I think my question was incorrectly formulated since I think that the lock only guarantees that  the humand instance is not modified. How ever, does it guarantees me that none of the some Object1 2 and 3 are modified anywhere else by the call of any other function (eventually in an other Human) ?? So, yes it's more Object1 2 and 3 that need to be locked.

Comment: I think you are right, you should lock someObject1-2 and 3 instead of anchor

Comment: Is there a function that locks every single attribute of an instance -- If not how to do it the more efficient way ? (Actually it could have been the question of this post -- I juste figured that out). I image somethink like children.lockMyParents();
children.doSomeThatModifyMyParentsAttribute();
children.unlockMyParents();

Comment: I think my question was incorrectly formulated since I think that the lock only guarantees that  the humand instance is not modified. How ever, does it guarantees me that none of the someObject1 2 and 3 are modified anywhere else by the call of any other function (eventually in an other Human) ??

Comment: You don't need to lock every single attribute, just something that is only associated with the given object, and is never changing. When an other thread comes to the lock, it sees that it has already been locked, and waites

Comment: I don't know what your functions are on the someObject 1,2,3 but it could be easier to implement the lock on those instead of modifyObject

Comment: I could be doing smth like: void modifyObject(){
        lock (someObject1) lock(someObject2)
        {   
            //[...] do some stuff that may require time and can modify 
        }
    }

} The problem could be a dead lock if another child (say e2) has same someObject1with e2.someObject1= someObject12 and e2.someObject2= someObject1.

Comment: Hoping that the scenario of my previous comment never happend (I've to find a way), this made my calculus go from 4.75 minutes to 1.5 minutes. Thanks you  for the advices !!!